# How to reset state of a child reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

I have a `react.js` app which loads data from an API displays a bunch of questions (`textboxes`, `radiolist`, `checkboxes`, etc). The user fills them in and submits all answers back to the API, which then send a new set of questions.

All these questions are in a single object, so I've created parent react.js component which holds the current set of questions in state. When the state changes it re-renders each question below. This works pretty much fine.

The problem is that sometimes the API displays the exact same question for twice in a row, but as this is held in state and react.js is clever enough to know it doesn't need to render a completely new component, because the old one will do (with a few small updates).

The problem is that if I select a radio button on the first one, based on the initial data stored in state of the child component, which was initially set within componentDidMount). But when the second question comes along, because its essentially the same component, the state remains. The constructor is not called again.

I think I should be using one of the other events, perhaps:

- `componentWillReceiveProps`
- `componentWillMount`
- `componentWillUpdate`

but I can't figure out which one is the most consistent one.

I basically want to reset the `selectedAnswer` everytime the parent has received new data from the API and essentially re-render all child components (but react won't do that).

**Edit**

I wonder instead of trying to reset this via the internal lifecycle events, whether I can pass in a different set of props into the component, so it can decide whether to re-create or re-render in the usual way.

Comment: change `key` of the component to tell `React` it's a *different* component.

Answer (score 0):

okay so to optimally do this lets suppose you api which returns the set of questions, it might contain some `id` associated with it. Using that id create a uniq key for every child component while rendering something like below

```
<Child key={`${data_id}_${index}`} />
```

This will ensure that for the same set they do not keep mounting again and again and will only mount if a new data set is fetched in which case data_id will change which would cause remounting of each and every child component

Comment: I tried fiddling with the key of the child component, but couldn't find any IDs which changed, other than using a datetime. It also feels a bit like a workaround. I wonder if I should be passing in an extra props into the component, so it can appropriate decide that is *should* re-create the component, rather than just pass new props to it.

Comment: actually keys is not a workaround. keys are present to manipulate how react reconciles dom itself

Answer (score 0):

I'd encourage you to check out Redux. It makes managing state much easier. I'd contribute some code on here but I am not sure I actually understand the question. If you linked us to your Github, then I could probably answer this specific question.

Also, it seems like you don't really need to touch state. It sounds more life attaching an event and controlling state that way. For example, using onSubmit, you can make an API call (and whatever else) and then have another function to reset the form state afterwards. It would be pretty straight forward, especially if you are using then/catch Promises.

Comment: I intend to use redux in the future, but wonder if that would resolve this problem, as its more about the lifecycle of a react.js component. I already use promises and events, but are you suggesting I don't need to hold that top-level data in state at all? In fact I never directly change that state and only pass it as props. i wonder if I need to adjust the props I pass into my component, so it can decide to re-create a component, rather than not.